# Disable \ Change WooCommerce's notify_url parameter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

Woocommerce is sending an "notify_url" parameter when sending a client to PayPal Payment gateway which overrides the default ipn address which is set in PayPal account of seller.

I don't want it to, because i have an ["ipn forwarder"](https://ipnforwarder.com/) address set in PayPal's ipn so i can easily send the same ipn message to multiple services like incoives and so...

I looked up the woocommerce documentations and couldn't find any action/hook/filter or so to disable it or change it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've researched the WooCommerce code and found the following filter you can use to unset the notify url:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'filter_woocommerce_paypal_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_paypal_args( array $args, WC_Order $order ): array {
    unset( $args['notify_url'] ); // Unset notify url

    return $args;
}
```

Goes into your child themes `functions.php` file.